# Reflection exception(Controller not found) in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I followed Laravel 5.2 online tutorial on creating intermediate tasks

So far the form

```
<form action="{{ url('task/'.$task->id) }}" method="POST">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
  {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}

  <button type="submit" id="delete-task-{{ $task->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">
  <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::delete('/task/{task}', 'TaskController@destroy');
```

Controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    $this->authorize('destroy', $task);
    $task->delete();

    return redirect('/tasks');
}
```

Inserting or adding tasks in form has no problem except when I hit delete button

> in Route.php line 285
>   at ReflectionParameter->getClass() in Route.php line 285
>   at Route->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(ReflectionParameter))
>   at array_filter(array(object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter)), object(Closure)) in Route.php line 286

I am using Laravel 5.2. How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it

I created Models folder and put all model files there, now in the Task Controller , I forgot to to call the model

```
 use App\Models\Task
```

And instead I used

```
 use App\Task
```

Just wondering why the errors is pointing to Task Controller as the culprit instead of the Task Model

Cheers